# Can Processor set specified state in NIFI-1.10.0?

Tags: apache-nifi

i know that Processor can record and clear state.If i wanna set a specificed state,for example,reseting the state to point to the tenth row of the column.IDK whether can do that?
Any help is appreciated!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this since it doesn't save previous data. 
Think of it as a map with `phy_asset@!@created_time` as key and `2020-03-23 13:29:05.0` as value. It doesn't know the previous values that it saved for this key.

It also cannot be changed by anyone but the processor.

What you can do, in your case at least, is to set `Additional WHERE clause` to `created_time >= '<wanted-minimum_creation_time>'` which would only query those with greater creation time than what you've chosen and will achieve the same result as you want.
Don't forget to reset the state though!